# Mismatch Detected for RunTimeLibrary ( MD DLL )

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a Win32 C++ project (AccountBuilder) with a configuration type of Application.exe and a Runtime Library of 'Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)' with a link to a lib file of another Win32 C++ project (ReportGenerator) with a configuration type of Static Library .lib also with a Runtime Library of 'Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)' in all configurations for both projects. However, I receive the following error:

> Error 1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value
> 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in
> Account.obj    File: Rpf.ReportGenerator(ReportGenerator.obj)    Project: AccountBuilder
>
> Error 2   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value
> 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in
> Account.obj    File: Rpf.ReportGenerator(FileType.obj)    Project: AccountBuilder

After reading other questions on the topic I thought to ensure that the runtime libraries match exactly and it seems they do. However, the project still will not build in Debug within VS 2012? What could I be missing? I've set the configuration for the Runtime Library to '/MD' for 'All Configurations' to no avail and attempted multiple rebuilds of both projects and manually deleting the intermediate obj files with no luck.

Comment: Make sure you use the debug library for the Debug config and a release library for the Release config. You seem to be trying to mix the configurations.

Comment: ***I've set the configuration for the Runtime Library to '/MD' for All Configurations*** That is wrong. You can't do that for Debug mode. For debug mode it will have to be `/MDd`

Comment: I thought so. However, I'm adding to an already large solution with many projects that had been configured to use /MD in debug ( incorrectly, I know ). However, they seem to function in debug mode. How are they able to do so? I've tried to mimic their property pages side by side and that yielded no results either.

Comment: The mismatch seems to originate only from the project with both a static ofstream and a static stringstream. Why does this trigger MD_DynamicDebug to be used instead of MD_DynamicRelease?